# TheGraph is not connecting to IPFS locally

Tags: events, ipfs, docker, graphs

I have a Graph local node set up using [this tutorial](https://thegraph.com/docs/quick-start#5.-deploy-the-subgraph-to-the-local-graph-node). When I am trying to deploy it, its not going through with the following error message:

```
 Add file to IPFS build/schema.graphql
⠋ Upload subgraph to IPFSFile:  {
  path: 'schema.graphql',
  content: <Buffer 74 79 70 65 20 6d 69 6e 74 65 64 4e 46 54 53 20 40 65 6e 74 69 74 79 7b 0a 20 20 69 64 3a 20 49 44 21 0a 20 20 23 73 6f 75 72 63 65 46 54 49 64 3a 20 ... 47 more bytes>
}
✖ Failed to upload subgraph to IPFS: Failed to upload file to IPFS: {"statusCode":404}
Error: Failed to upload file to IPFS: {"statusCode":404}
```

In my Docker setup IPFS is defined as:

```
ipfs: 'ipfs:5001'
```

when calling from graph:

```
"deploy-local": "graph deploy --node http://localhost:8020/ --ipfs http://127.0.0.1:5001/ **/**"
```

Any ideas on what to try next? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I had RemixIDE running on port 5001 and subgraph didn't give me a "port unavailable" error or anything. Turning off RemixIDE solved the problem.